# how do I build dictionary from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to build dictionary from string can someone help me to build the efficient way.

I have api which takes string with comma separate value and returns if value if API has matching values
example:

```
# my paramaters to my API car, bike, moter-cycle, airplane, boat

# www.api.com?words=car,bike,moter-cycle,airplane,boat


field_json = json.loads(response.text)
data = field_json['response']

list1=""
for i in data['docs']:
    list[i['keyword_s']]= i['url_s']
    list1 = str(list)
    print(list)

return list1
```

from above I just get

```
{'bike':'http://bikes.com/bikes',
 'boat':'http://boat.com/boat'}
```

if API find bike and boat as matching I would need my dictonary as

```
{'car':'none',
 'bike':'http://bikes.com/bikes',
 'moter-cycle': 'none',
 'airplane':'none',
 'boat':'http://boat.com/boat'
 }
```

Comment: What is `list` in your code? Can you show the json returned by the API?

Comment: list is a dictionary and  is empty as I get the values I add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to involve strings, just fill in hole values in your returned api response

```
dict_a = {'bike':'http://bikes.com/bikes', 'boat':'http://boat.com/boat'}
keywords = ['car','bike','motorcycle', 'airplane', 'boat'] 

dict_b = {k: None for k in keywords}

dict_b.update(dict_a)
print(dict_b)
```

Output

```
{'car': None, 'bike': 'http://bikes.com/bikes', 'motorcycle': None, 'airplane': None, 'boat': 'http://boat.com/boat'}
```

Comment: perfect this is working I had been passing string to update.

Comment: can you help me how can i do that using list or tuples ?

Comment: Do what? You should ask it as a new question complete with what you've tried and researched

Comment: sure I will post as new question, your solution works but problem is it removes duplicates example : keywords = ['car','bike','motorcycle', 'airplane', 'boat', 'boat'] I still need  {'car': None, 'bike': 'http://bikes.com/bikes', 'motorcycle': None, 'airplane': None, 'boat': 'http://boat.com/boat',  'boat': 'http://boat.com/boat'} I realized lately that I cannot retain duplicate in dictionary so trying to use list or duplicates